# How to set a background photo opacity to 0.5 but not affect the text that it is placed on it?

Tags: html, css

So I have this code right here, 3 boxes each have a background photo(set with url on CSS, not  added in HTML). I'm trying to make the photo darker because the white text does not look good at the moment. When I try to do that, it makes everything opaque, including the text.

```css
#box-one,
#box-two,
#box-three {
  font-size: 25px;
  padding: 30px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  box-shadow: 15px 15px 13px #aa924ba8;
}

#box-one {
  background: url(./img/barsana.jpg);
}

#box-two {
  background: url(./img/mocanita.jpg);
}

#box-three {
  background: url(./img/food.jpg);
}
```

```html
<div class="container-hl">
  <div id="box-one">
    <h3>Barsana</h3>
    <hr />
    <p>Built in 1970, located in the homonymous village, on a beautiful hilltop</p>
  </div>

  <div id="box-two">
    <h3>Info</h3>
    <hr />
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam, beatae id. Ducimus?</p>
  </div>

  <div id="box-three">
    <h3>Info</h3>
    <hr />
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Add an absolutely positioned div/pseudo elelemt over the image (height and width 100%), under the text and give that a black background and adjust the opacity of it

Answer (score 1):

CSS allows us to layer backgrounds by providing multiple comma-separated values to the background property. I would use this to your advantage and get creative with multiple backgrounds.

```
#box-one {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), cover no-repeat url(./img/barsana.jpg);
}

#box-two {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), cover no-repeat url(./img/mocanita.jpg);
}

#box-three {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), cover no-repeat url(./img/food.jpg);
}
```

Instead of making the element opaque, the above code instead applies a dark overlay to the background image, allowing your white text to be more eligible.